# Can't launch my Ubuntu touch application into my Aquaris e4.5

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

I have created a simple application on Ubuntu touch that read barcode.

It works very well on desktop but impossible to launch it into my Aquaris E4.5

Here is my console output:

```
 Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:10000' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Sdk-Launcher> Executing:     /tmp/qfacts.nymeria_0.1_armhf.click
Sdk-Launcher> Force Install: False
Sdk-Launcher> Skip Uninstall:False
Sdk-Launcher> Launcher PID: 9544
Sdk-Launcher> Installing application .....
Transaction:    Installing files
Status:     Waiting in queue
Status:     Starting
Status:     Finished
Transaction:    Installing files
Status:     Waiting in queue
Status:     Waiting for authentication
Status:     Waiting in queue
Status:     Starting
Status:     Finished
Results:
Installed    qfacts.nymeria-0.1.armhf (installed:click,removable=1,app_name=QFacts)
Sdk-Launcher> Application installed successfully
Sdk-Launcher> AppId:                   qfacts.nymeria_QFacts_0.1
Sdk-Launcher> Architecture:            armhf
Sdk-Launcher> Application confined:    True
Sdk-Launcher> Communication directory: /home/phablet/.local/share/qfacts.nymeria/
Sdk-Launcher> Application started: 9679
Sdk-Launcher> Received a failed event
Sdk-Launcher> The Application exited, cleaning up
Sdk-Launcher> Finished
```

My smartphone is in developer mode, connected through USB. I didn't understand why I receive a `failed event`.

The source code is available here:
http://www.jeodrive.com/download/qfacts-tar/

If you have any idea, please tell me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because the .pro of my module wasn't declare properly.
Thank you to Chris Wayne (on google+) to help me to detect the bug.